# retrieving a post variable in python from jquery

Tags: jquery, python

I'm a python newbie. I'm trying to use python to query a database. I need to pass some parameters to the python page so it can query the database. But I'm having trouble retrieving post variables.

html:

```
<select class="chooseRace" id="race">
                    <option value="president">Presidential</option>
                    <option value="governor">Gubernatorial</option>
                    <option value="senate">Senatorial</option>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
var e = document.getElementById("race");
var strRace = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/py/getRaces.py",
    method: "POST",
    data: {level: strLevel},
    success: function(data) {
        // Successful POST; do something with the response if you want
        console.log("ok, it worked. ");
    },
    error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
        // Error, handle it
        console.log(statusText + " " + err);
    }
});
```

python:

```
import MySQLdb
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import json
import requests

print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
print 
print request.POST['level'] # for POST form method

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="user", # your username
                      passwd="pass", # your password
                      db="my_dbs") # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor() 

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
```

But when I run localhost/py/getRaces.py, I get this:

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>   Python 2.7.8: C:\Python27\python.exe
Tue Jul 22 14:58:21 2014
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 C:\code\getRaces.py in ()
      7 print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
      8 print 
=>    9 print request.POST['level'] # for POST form method
     10  
     11 db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
request undefined
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'request' is not defined 
      args = ("name 'request' is not defined",) 
      message = "name 'request' is not defined"
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I thought I installed the requests library.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be the following:

```
print requests.post['level'] # for POST form method
```

The error message indicates that there is no such thing as 'request' in your program.

Comment: I changed the line to print requests.POST['level'], and the error message is <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'POST'

Comment: Edited my answer; didn't account for case sensitivity.

Comment: causes the error: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__' 
      args = ("'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'",) 
      message = "'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: Alright, so somewhere else in your code something is asking for a getitem attribute on an object and not finding it. We've solved your intial issue only to find more with the script. Progress! :)

Comment: `print requests.POST['level']` => `print requests.POST('level')`? or possibly `print request.POST()['level']`? Although `'level'` appears not to be defined, so will probably cause a `NameError`...

Comment: @SiHa: 'level' is set in the jquery var e = document.getElementById("race");
var strRace = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/py/getRaces.py",
    method: "POST",
    data: {level: strLevel},
    success: function(data) {
        // Successful POST; do something with the response if you want
        console.log("ok, it worked. ");
    },
    error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
        // Error, handle it
        console.log(statusText + " " + err);
    }
});

Comment: Is there some place in your code referencing a 'getitem' attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Which framework are you using?

You are trying to access an object that should hold your recieved data, but it's not defined at function scope or not present at all in your framework.